# Query related to Google Apps for business

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I have configured Google Apps for business, such that I have now created a Gmail address as `someone@abc.com`. However, I used to initially access my mails via Squirrel mail with the same id—`someone@abc.com`. Now I want to setup a POP3 forwarding on Gmail so as to receive the mails on Squirrel mail. However, I am receiving an error saying that I cannot do this because the forwarding email address is the same as the Gmail. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: do you want to receive your emails on squirrel mail, not gmail? can i ask why?

Answer (score 1):

If you redirect mail from `someone@abc.com` to `someone@abc.com` what will end up happening in your Gmail account is the MX records point to Gmail MX servers.

You can enable IMAP/POP access on individual accounts and setup Squirrelmail to access to those accounts but I don't think it's a good idea.

In my opinion you should forget Squirrelmail and switch completely to Gmail.